# Этимология слова "знахарь"

Tags: этимология

Каково происхождение слова "знахарь"? Оно имеет что-то общее со словом "знание"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ лежит на поверхности, вы сами практически ответили на свой вопрос: слово ЗНАХАРЬ образовано от глагола ЗНАТЬ. Словообразование здесь аналогично словам писарь (<писать), жихарь (<жить), косарь (<косить), пахарь (<пахать) и т.п. (Словарь Фасмера подтверждает эту версию.)